# How to use list comprehension to mutate the original list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

Why does list comprehension not change the original list like a for loop? List comprehension seems like a simpler solution.

Problem statement:
Implement a function map_mut that takes a list as an argument and maps a function f onto each element of the list. You should mutate the original lists, without creating any new lists. Do NOT return anything.

Wrong way with list comprehension:

```
def map_mut(f, L):
    '''
    >>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> map_mut(lambda x: x**2, L)
    >>> L
    [1, 4, 9, 16]
    '''
    L = [f(x) for x in L]
```

Right way with a for loop:

```
def map_mut(f, L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i] = f(L[i])
```

Comment: Variable assignment doesn't mutate objects. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: It is bad practice to mutate method arguments unless you are quite sure that the performance optimization is necessary. I think you would be better off with `L = map_mut(lambda x: x**2, L)`. Your method implementation would stay the same, but you need to `return L` to pass that back to the caller.

Comment: Quite often you don't *want* to change the original list. If you do want to, there are many ways, including simply assigning the comprehension to the same variable.

Comment: I think the best you can do is `L[:] = map(f, x)`, or alternatively `L[:] = (f(x) for x in L)`.  These both modify the original `L`, so any references to it would pick up the changes.

Comment: If you really want to mutate with list comprehension (which I do **not** recommend), you could do this: `[(L.pop(0), L.append(function(i)) for i in L.copy()]`

Comment: lists are mutable : that means you can change there state ( data ) but it will still point to the same memory address
`my_list = [1,2,3] # memory address of 0x500`
if we call `my_list.append(4)` similar to what you are doing with the for loop
my_list will be `[1,2,3,4]` and the memory address will be `0x500`
but if we do something like
`my_list = my_list + [4]`
the result will be` [1,2,3,4]` but the memory address will change` 0x600` because` [4]` is a new object with a new reference and that's similar to what list comprehension do , it create a new object different from the original one

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Thank you. I was reading through the other links but when you said the list comprehension makes a new object it clicked. I  guess under the current circumstances a for loop would be easier.

Comment: @rocket_man I was typing a comprehensive answer but got notified , it got closed .

Comment: @AhmedSoliman they closed it. Thanks for helping though.